# Period from getdate() function in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

How can we get the period from getdate() function in sql?
I tried below
`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 106)` but this gives the result in dd mmm yyyy format.
I want the result to be like 202009 (YYYYmm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMM');
```

Or

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112);
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found it
Its

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, GetDate(),112),6)
```

Comment: You should always set the length for `N/VARCHAR(n)`